# Prove that there exists a number α > 0 such that f(x) > α for all $x \in I$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, real-numbers

I = [a, b] and let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that f(x) > 0 for each
$x \in I$. Prove that there exists a number α > 0 such that f(x) > α  for all $x \in I$.

Comment: Hint: $f$ attains a minimum value in $I$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Assume that there isn't... What would happen then?

Comment: only thing  that come in mind is  intermediate value and maxima.

Comment: @ashishkumar What the problem asks to prove is that the continuous function over a closed segment is bounded. You should be able to find the proof in any textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L = inf_{x \in I} f(x)$. Since $f$ is a continuous function,  $\exists x_0 \in I $ such that $0<f(x_0)=L$. Take $a = \frac L2$. Then $f(x)>a \forall x \in I$.